# can I pass arguments to my function through add_action?

Tags: php, wordpress

can I do something like that? to pass arguments to my function? I already studied [add_action doc](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) but did not figure out how to do it. What the exact syntax to pass two arguments would look like. In particular how to pass **text & integer arguments**.

```
function recent_post_by_author($author,$number_of_posts) {
  some commands;
}
add_action('thesis_hook_before_post','recent_post_by_author',10,'author,2')
```

**UPDATE**

it seems to me that it is done somehow through [do_action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_action) but how? :-)

Answer (score 79):

> can I do something like that? to pass arguments to my function?

Yes you can! The trick really is in what type of function you pass to [add_action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) and what you expect from [do_action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_action).

- ‘my_function_name’
- array( instance, ‘instance_function_name’)
- ‘StaticClassName::a_function_on_static_class'
- anonymous
- lambda
- closure

---

We can do it with a [closure](http://culttt.com/2013/03/25/what-are-php-lambdas-and-closures/).

```
// custom args for hook

$args = array (
    'author'        =>  6, // id
    'posts_per_page'=>  1, // max posts
);

// subscribe to the hook w/custom args

add_action('thesis_hook_before_post', 
           function() use ( $args ) { 
               recent_post_by_author( $args ); });


// trigger the hook somewhere

do_action( 'thesis_hook_before_post' );


// renders a list of post tiles by author

function recent_post_by_author( $args ) {

    // merge w/default args
    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, array (
        'author'        =>  -1,
        'orderby'       =>  'post_date',
        'order'         =>  'ASC',
        'posts_per_page'=>  25
    ));

    // pull the user's posts
    $user_posts = get_posts( $args );

    // some commands
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ( $user_posts as $post ) {
        echo "<li>$post->post_title</li>";
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

---

Here is a simplified example of a closure working

```
$total = array();

add_action('count_em_dude', function() use (&$total) { $total[] = count($total); } );

do_action ('count_em_dude' );
do_action ('count_em_dude' );
do_action ('count_em_dude' );
do_action ('count_em_dude' );
do_action ('count_em_dude' );
do_action ('count_em_dude' );
do_action ('count_em_dude' );

echo implode ( ', ', $total ); // 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

---

Anonymous vs. Closure

```
add_action ('custom_action', function(){ echo 'anonymous functions work without args!'; } ); //

add_action ('custom_action', function($a, $b, $c, $d){ echo 'anonymous functions work but default args num is 1, the rest are null - '; var_dump(array($a,$b,$c,$d)); } ); // a

add_action ('custom_action', function($a, $b, $c, $d){ echo 'anonymous functions work if you specify number of args after priority - '; var_dump(array($a,$b,$c,$d)); }, 10, 4 ); // a,b,c,d

// CLOSURE

$value = 12345;
add_action ('custom_action', function($a, $b, $c, $d) use ($value) { echo 'closures allow you to include values - '; var_dump(array($a,$b,$c,$d, $value)); }, 10, 4 ); // a,b,c,d, 12345

// DO IT!

do_action( 'custom_action', 'aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd' );
```

---

Proxy Function Class

```
class ProxyFunc {
    public $args = null;
    public $func = null;
    public $location = null;
    public $func_args = null;
    function __construct($func, $args, $location='after', $action='', $priority = 10, $accepted_args = 1) {
        $this->func = $func;
        $this->args = is_array($args) ? $args : array($args);
        $this->location = $location;
        if( ! empty($action) ){
            // (optional) pass action in constructor to automatically subscribe
            add_action($action, $this, $priority, $accepted_args );
        }
    }
    function __invoke() {
        // current arguments passed to invoke
        $this->func_args = func_get_args();

        // position of stored arguments
        switch($this->location){
            case 'after':
                $args = array_merge($this->func_args, $this->args );
                break;
            case 'before':
                $args = array_merge($this->args, $this->func_args );
                break;
            case 'replace':
                $args = $this->args;
                break;
            case 'reference':
                // only pass reference to this object
                $args = array($this);
                break;
            default:
                // ignore stored args
                $args = $this->func_args;
        }

        // trigger the callback
        call_user_func_array( $this->func, $args );

        // clear current args
        $this->func_args = null;
    }
}
```

Example Usage #1

```
$proxyFunc = new ProxyFunc(
    function() {
        echo "<pre>"; print_r( func_get_args() ); wp_die();
    },
    array(1,2,3), 'after'
);

add_action('TestProxyFunc', $proxyFunc );
do_action('TestProxyFunc', 'Hello World', 'Goodbye'); // Hello World, 1, 2, 3
```

Example Usage #2

```
$proxyFunc = new ProxyFunc(
    function() {
        echo "<pre>"; print_r( func_get_args() ); wp_die();
    },                  // callback function
    array(1,2,3),       // stored args
    'after',            // position of stored args
    'TestProxyFunc',    // (optional) action
    10,                 // (optional) priority
    2                   // (optional) increase the action args length.
);
do_action('TestProxyFunc', 'Hello World', 'Goodbye'); // Hello World, Goodbye, 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: For whoever using the `ProxyFunc` approach: If your `do_action` is not passing any `args` then the last parameter to `new ProxyFunc(...)` MUST be passed as `0`. Otherwise your `function` gets an empty string as first parameter.

Comment: First part of this response (ref closure) is the answer to look at without doubt.

Answer (score 53):

Instead of:

```
add_action('thesis_hook_before_post','recent_post_by_author',10,'author,2')
```

it should be:

```
add_action('thesis_hook_before_post','recent_post_by_author',10,2)
```

...where 2 is the number of arguments and 10 is the priority in which the function will be executed. You don't list your arguments in add_action. This initially tripped me up. Your function then looks like this:

```
function function_name ( $arg1, $arg2 ) { /* do stuff here */ }
```

Both the add_action and function go in functions.php and you specify your arguments in the template file (page.php for example) with do_action like so:

```
do_action( 'name-of-action', $arg1, $arg2 );
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Bart - you just saved me from going down a closure/anonymous functions hole lol

Answer (score 21):

### Build custom WP functions with classes

This is easy with classes, as you can set object variables with the constructor, and use them in any class method. So for an example, here's how adding meta boxes could work in classes...

```
// Array to pass to class
$data = array(
    "meta_id" => "custom_wp_meta",
    "a" => true,
    "b" => true,
    // etc...
);

// Init class
$var = new yourWpClass ($data);

// Class
class yourWpClass {

    // Pass $data var to class
    function __construct($init) {
        $this->box = $init; // Get data in var
        $this->meta_id = $init["meta_id"];
        add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array(&$this, '_reg_meta') );
    }
    public function _reg_meta() {
        add_meta_box(
            $this->meta_id,
            // etc ....
        );
    }
}
```

If you consider `__construct($arg)` the same as `function functionname($arg)` then you should be able to avoid global variables and pass all the information you need through to any functions in the class object.

These pages seem to be good points of reference when building wordpress meta / plugins ->

- http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/2010/05/howto-meta-box-wordpress.html
- https://gist.github.com/1880770

Comment: This is a must if you don't control the call to do_action

Comment: How Word Press plugins should be coded. Good to see this suggestion!

Answer (score 12):

### 7 Ways to pass data to `add_action` function

1. Through `do_action` (if you yourself create actions)
2. `wp_localize_script` approach (if you need to pass data to JavaScript)
3. Using `use` in Closures/Anonymous/Lamda functions
4. Make use of arrow functions (PHP 7.4+)
5. Use `add_filter`, `apply_filters` as a transport (clever way)
6. Hack the scope with `global` or `$GLOBALS` (if you are desperate)
7. Use `set_transient`, `get_transient` and other functions as a transport (in case of exotic necesities)

### **#1 Through `do_action`**

if you have access to the code where the action fires, pass variables through `do_action`:

```
/**
* Our client code
*
* Here we recieve required variables.
*/
function bar($data1, $data2, $data3) {
    /**
     * It's not necessary that names of these variables match 
     * the names of the variables we pass bellow in do_action.
     */

    echo $data1 . $data2 . $data3;
}
add_action( 'foo', 'bar', 10, 3 );

/**
 * The code where action fires
 *
 * Here we pass required variables.
 */
$data1 = '1';
$data2 = '2';
$data3 = '3';
//...
do_action( 'foo', $data1, $data2, $data3 /*, .... */ );
```

### #2 `wp_localize_script` approach

if you need to pass variable to JavaScript, this is the best way of doing it.

**functions.php**

```
/**
 * Enqueue script
 */
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/my-script.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, false );
} );

/**
 * Pass data to the script as an object with name `my_data`
 */
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function(){
    wp_localize_script( 'my_script', 'my_data', [
        'bar' => 'some data',
        'foo' => 'something else'
    ] );
} );
```

**my-script.js**

```
alert(my_data.bar); // "some data"
alert(my_data.foo); // "something else"
```

Basically the same but without `wp_localize_script`:

**functions.php**

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function(){
    echo <<<EOT
    <script> 
    window.my_data = { 'bar' : 'somedata', 'foo' : 'something else' };
    </script>;
    EOT;

    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/my-script.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, false );
}, 10, 1 );
```

### #3 Using `use` in Closures/Anonymous/Lamda functions

if you don't have access to the code where the action fires you can slip the data as follows (PHP 5.3+):

```
$data1 = '1';
$data2 = '2';
$data3 = '3';

add_action( 'init', function() use ($data1, $data2, $data3) {
    echo $data1 . $data2 . $data3; // 123
});
```

### #4 Make use of arrow functions (PHP 7.4+)

Basically the same as the #3 example but more concise, as the arrow functions involve variables from the parent scope without using `use`:

```
$data1 = '1';
$data2 = '2';
$data3 = '3';

add_action( 'init', fn() => print( $data1 . $data2 . $data3 ) ); // prints "123"
```

### #5 Use `add_filter`, `apply_filters` as a transport

You can create a function with `add_filter` that will return value when you call `apply_filters`:

```
/**
 * Register the data with the filter functions
 */
add_filter( 'data_1', function() { return '1'; } );
add_filter( 'data_2', function() { return '2'; } );
add_filter( 'data_3', fn() => '3' ); // or in concise way with arrow function

function foo() {
    /**
     * Get the previously registered data
     */
    echo apply_filters( 'data_1', null ) . 
         apply_filters( 'data_2', null ) . 
         apply_filters( 'data_3', null ); // 123
}
add_action( 'init', 'foo');
```

I have seen the approach applied in many plugins.

### #6 Hack the scope with `global` or `$GLOBALS` (kiddy way)

If you don't worry about the scope, use `global`, **example #1:**

```
$data1 = '1';
$data2 = '2';
$data3 = '3';

function foo() {
    global $data1, $data2, $data3;

    echo $data1 . $data2 . $data3; // 123
}
add_action( 'init', 'foo' );
```

**Example #2** Using `$GLOBALS` instead of `global`

```
$data1 = '1';
$data2 = '2';
$data3 = '3';

function foo() {
    echo $GLOBALS['data1'] . $GLOBALS['data2'] . $GLOBALS['data3']; // 123
}
add_action( 'init', 'foo' );
```

### #7 Use `set_transient`, `get_transient`, `set_query_var`, `get_query_var` as a transport

**Example #1:** Let's say there is a shortcode that prints a form, that subsequently gets submitted and handled via AJAX, and the data is coming from the form must be sent by email that should be gotten from the shortcode parameters.

1. Init shortcode
2. Parse and print shortcode, remember parameters to transients

--- Within Ajax handler ---

3. Get required parameters from the transient and send the email.

**Example #2:** Before Wordpress 5.5 came out, some people had passed parameters within `wp_query` by `get/set_query_vars` to pass them to the template parts, these can be used as well.

Mix them up and use. Cheers.

Answer (score 9):

Basically the `do_action` is placed where the action should be executed, and it needs a name plus your custom parameters.

When you come to call the function using add_action, pass the name of your `do_action()` as your first argument, and the function name as the second. So something like:

```
function recent_post_by_author($author,$number_of_posts) {
  some commands;
}
add_action('get_the_data','recent_post_by_author',10,'author,2');
```

This is where it's executed

```
do_action('get_the_data',$author,$number_of_posts);
```

Should hopefully work.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but do_action. I believe that do_action is handled by Thesis and I shouldn't touch that...

Comment: So I take it thesis_hook_before_post is a custom hook you've added that's already tied to an action? Is it worth combining your actions, or adding an additional one? Sorry this isn't getting you closer to an answer very quickly, but code in the WP hooks system tends to get really muddled really quickly so it's difficult to pick apart what's needed.

Comment: I do not know how to add some action to existing Thesis one. I'd say it's not worth to do

Answer (score 6):

Pass in vars from the local scope FIRST, then pass the `fn` SECOND:

```
$fn = function() use($pollId){ 
   echo "<p>NO POLLS FOUND FOR POLL ID $pollId</p>"; 
};
add_action('admin_notices', $fn);
```

Answer (score 4):

I use closure for PHP 5.3+. I can then pass the default values and mine without globals. (example for add_filter)

```
...
$tt="try this";

add_filter( 'the_posts', function($posts,$query=false) use ($tt) {
echo $tt;
print_r($posts);
return  $posts;
} );
```

Comment: Thanks Miguel, anonymous functions (closures) worked for me for actions and filters.

Answer (score 4):

Well, this is old, but it has no accepted answer. Reviving so that Google searchers have some hope.

If you have an existing `add_action` call that doesn't accept arguments like this:

```
function my_function() {
  echo 100;
}

add_action('wp_footer', 'my_function');
```

You can pass an argument to that function by using an anonymous function as the callback like this:

```
function my_function($number) {
  echo $number;
}

$number = 101;
add_action('wp_footer', function() { global $number; my_function($number); });
```

Depending on your use case, you might need to use different forms of callback, possibly even using properly declared functions, as sometimes you may encounter trouble with scope.

Comment: Simple explanation and easy to understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same thing today, and since all answers here are either unclear, irrelevant or excessive, I thought I'd provide the simple straight-forward answer.

Like the most popular answer here already states, you should use an anonymous function to achieve what you'd like to do. But, what deserves some extra attention IMO, is the  the benefit of passing the available parameters of the action to your function.

If somewhere, an action hook is defined like this:

```
do_action('cool_action_name', $first_param, $second_param);
```

You can pass the values of `$first_param` and `$second_param` to your own function, and add your own params like this:

```
add_action('cool_action_name', 
    function ($first_param, $second_param) {
        // Assuming you're working in a class, so $this is the scope.
        $this->your_cool_method($first_param, $second_param, 'something_else'); 
    }
);
```

Then you can use all the values in your method, like this:

```
public function your_cool_method($first_param, $second_param, $something_else)
{
    // Do something with the params.
}
```

Comment: Add the `use()` to enable usage pf external variables in the closure and that will be the shortest answer that does it all.

Answer (score 1):

I've wrote wordpress plugin long time ago, but I went to Wordpress Codex and I think that's possible: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action

```
<?php add_action( $tag, $function_to_add, $priority, $accepted_args ); ?>
```

I think you should pass them as an array. Look under examples "take arguments".

Bye

Comment: I did what you suggested before asking my Question. I did not figure out how I can pass text & integer arguments.

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't notice it must be an (int). Sorry. Well, don't you pass arguments through do_action_ref_array usually? I mean you first declare you action and then you use it with do_action.

Comment: I can probably code it differently but if I want to reuse the function somewhere else it would be nice to be able pass some arguments to it, wouldn't it be

Comment: Ok, but the add_action function, for what I can understand reading more carefully the Codex, is just a way to hook up your function to the system through an action, so I don't think is in its design to accept more arguments. In your definition of the function you can use parametric parameters but then you have to pass actual parameter using do_action or do_action_ref_array.
I can be wrong of course. But if there is a way, I'm sorry, I don't know it.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue and solved it by using global variables. Like so:

```
global $myvar;
$myvar = value;
add_action('hook', 'myfunction');

function myfunction() {
    global $myvar;
}
```

A bit sloppy but it works.

Comment: sadface for global vars :(

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply as this:

```
function recent_post_by_author_related($author,$number_of_posts) {
    // some commands;
}

function recent_post_by_author() {
    recent_post_by_author_related($foo, $bar);
}
add_action('thesis_hook_before_post','recent_post_by_author')
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add this here so that when I search for this next year, I know where to find this. This is modified from the latest WordPress documentation.

Here is how to do it from [WordPress's documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_action/).

```
// The action callback function.
function example_callback( $arg1, $arg2 ) {
    // (maybe) do something with the args to get a value.
    return $value;
}
add_action( 'example_action', 'example_callback', 10, 2 ); 
// the 2 above specifies the number of args

/*
 * Trigger the actions by calling the 'example_callback()' function
 * that's hooked onto `example_action` above.
 *
 * - 'example_action' is the action hook.
 * - $arg1 and $arg2 are the additional arguments passed to the callback.
 */
$value = do_action( 'example_action', $arg1, $arg2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass parameters to the callable function, instead of the do_action, you can call an anonymous function. Example:

```
// Route Web Requests
add_action('shutdown', function() {
    Router::singleton()->routeRequests('app.php');
});
```

You see that `do_action('shutdown')` don't accept any parameters, but `routeRequests` does.

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
function reset_header() {
    ob_start();
}
add_action('init', 'reset_header');
```

then

```
reset_header();
wp_redirect( $approvalUrl);
```

More info https://tommcfarlin.com/wp_redirect-headers-already-sent/

Answer (score -3):

I have made a code to send parameters and process.

```
function recibe_data_post() {

$post_data = $_POST;

if (isset($post_data)) {

    if (isset($post_data['lista_negra'])) {

        $args = array (
            'btn'  =>  'lista_negra',
            'estado'=>  $post_data['lista_negra'],
        );

        add_action('template_redirect',
                   function() use ( $args ) {
                       recibe_parametros_btn( $args ); });
    }
    if (isset($post_data['seleccionado'])) {
        $args = array (
            'btn'  =>  'seleccionado',
            'estado'=>  $post_data['seleccionado'],
        );

        add_action('template_redirect',
                   function() use ( $args ) {
                       recibe_parametros_btn( $args ); });

        }
    }
}

    add_action( 'init', 'recibe_data_post' );

function recibe_parametros_btn( $args ) {

$data_enc = json_encode($args);
$data_dec = json_decode($data_enc);

$btn = $data_dec->btn;
$estado = $data_dec->estado;

fdav_procesa_botones($btn, $estado);

}

function fdav_procesa_botones($btn, int $estado) {

$post_id = get_the_ID();
$data = get_post($post_id);

if ( $estado == 1 ) {
    update_field($btn, 0, $post_id);
    } elseif ( $estado == 0 ) {
       update_field($btn, 1, $post_id);
    }

}
```

Comment: If you're going to provide an answer that is mostly code, at least explain what it does.