# passing argument using add_action in wordpress!

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a very strange problem in my wordpress development,

in fucntions.php I have the following code

```
//mytheme/functions.php
$arg = "HELP ME";
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_function', 10, 1);
do_action('admin_menu',$arg );

function my_function($arg)
{   
    echo "the var is:".$arg."<br>";
}
```

the output is

```
the var is:HELP ME
the var is:
```

Why the function repeated 2 times? Why has the argument "help me" been passed correctly and the 2nd time it havent been passed?

I have been trying all my best for 2 days and searched in many places to find a solution but I had no luck.

What I am trying to do is simple! I just want to pass argument to a function using add_action?

Comment: add_action? do_action? what is it?

Comment: @OZ_: these are some wordpress predefined functions, see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action  ,thanks

Answer (score 0):

Inside "my_function" (albeit it's yours :)), write line:

```
print_r(debug_backtrace());
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php
It will help you to know, what are going on.

Or, you can use [XDebug](http://www.xdebug.org/) (on development server).

Answer (score 0):

Well, first off, in your my_function() function, you're not *defining* $arg. You're trying to echo something out that isn't there - so when it's returned, it's empty.  So you need to define it. (edited to add: you're *trying* to define it outside the function - but to make the function *inside* recognize it, you have to globalize the argument.)

```
function my_function($arg) {  
    if(!$arg) $arg = 'some value'; 
    echo "the var is:".$arg."<br>";
}
```

when you add_action, you need to define the $arg value:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_function', 10, 'my value');
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to put your function before add_action ?

Answer (score 0):

Use an anonymous function like this:

```
function my_function($arg) {
  echo "the var is: $arg<br>";
}
$arg = "HELP ME";
add_action('admin_menu', function() { global $arg; my_function($arg); }, 10);
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31330519/1463157) for details.