# wordpress add_action pass variable

Tags: php, wordpress, function, arguments, closures

I have created a Wordpress function to display a slideshow in any page. The function works well and I can add a function call to any of my template pages to display a slideshow.

sample function call: `add_slideshow($slideshow_id, $gallery_id, $show_navigation_handles);`

I have hardcoded the jquery in the footer. However, I want to use `add_action('wp_footer','')` in my main function to add the jquery to the footer, because each slideshow may have different settings (different slideshow_id, gallery_id etc).

Here is my function:

```
function add_slideshow($slider_id, $gal_id, $show_controls){
//get the slideshow images from database and return HTML - A Bit Long to show here but it WORKS!

//add the required script to footer - JavaScript is added to footer but not $slider_id
add_action('wp_footer', function() { 
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function(){ 
            $('#" . $slider_id . "').flexslider();
        });
    </script>";
  });
```

But the PHP variable `$slider_id` is not being passed into the emitted javascript, such that the output in my footer is:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $('#').flexslider();
    });
</script>
```

When it should be eg this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $('#some_id_here').flexslider();
    });
</script>
```

If I manually add this to my footer with the correct id (#actual_slideshow_id) the slideshow plays OK.

I have searched this site for the last hour to try to find a solution but I couldn't find any that I could adapt to my specific problem.

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: So what's your problem/question?

Comment: $('#').flexslider(); should show actual id eg $('#my_slideshow_id').flexslider(); The PHP variable is not being passed.

Comment: I should mention that add_action is inside the add_slideshow function and works fine apart from the fact that the variable $slider_id is not output to the footer along with the generated JavaScript.

Comment: Updated my answer to include why $slider_id wasn't available in your anonymous function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1. Missing value (the answer to your question):**

Firstly, the reason your $slider_id isn't available in your anonymous function is because you haven't included it in the closure with a `use ($slider_id)` like this:

```
add_action('wp_footer', function($arguments) use ($slider_id) { 
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function(){ 
            $('#" . $slider_id . "').flexslider();
        });
    </script>";
}, $priority_integer, $accepted_arguments_integer);
```

**2. Using anonymous functions in the `add_action()` method:**

From the [WordPress Codex for add_action()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action):

> add_action( $tag, $function_to_add, $priority, $accepted_args );
>
> Parameters
>
> ...
>
> $function_to_add (callback) (required) The name of the
>   function you wish to be called. **Note: Only string-formatted syntaxes listed in the PHP documentation for the 'callback' type are valid**. [my emphasis]
>
> ...

Be aware that closures (aka anonymous functions) only work as callbacks in PHP 5.3+, and I (personally) wouldn't rely on them for this as long as the codex states that only string-formatted syntaxes are allowed (even though that same article does later use a closure-based example).

**3. Emitting a script:**

You should be using register_script and enqueue_script as per this answer at [WordPress Answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41204/enqueue-and-localize-script-in-footer)

(There's a bool parameter to state if script goes in footer or not).

To pass your specific arguments to the script at run-time, use the localize script approach.  A tutorial for this is at [Otto on Wordpress](http://ottopress.com/tag/wp_localize_script/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: $accepted_args is an int - number of args to pass. How do I actually pass these args?

Comment: @Markol Your function (at least, as it's written) doesn't accept any args anyway.  But yes, it's not intuitive.  They're passed when the action is executed, using `do_action()` [Codex - do_action()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_action)

Comment: I have tried do_action also but to no avail. Should add_action and do_action be outside the add_slideshow function? If so how do I pass a variable from the add_slideshow function to the do_action call?

Comment: OK I will try that now. Thanks for your help. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: wp_localize_script has worked almost perfectly. I want to be able to add the script multiple times with different parameters, so that each time I call the function, the following code is executed with a different value for $slider_id.

`wp_enqueue_script(
    $slider_id,
    get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/javascripts/include_flexslider.js'
);

$params = array(
  'slider_id' => $slider_id
);

wp_localize_script( $slider_id, 'MyScriptParams', $params );`

Comment: flexslider is the JS slideshow that I use and if I want to include multiple slideshows on a page with different settings for speed, fade style etc, I need to add a new flexslider jquery call for that slideshow e.g.

`$('#slideshow1').flexslider({slideshowSpeed: 7000});
$('#slideshow2').flexslider({slideshowSpeed: 3000});`

However, using localize_script, the first set of paramaters passed to my enqueued script are overridden by the second set.

Comment: I have registered multiple instances with different handle names and localised them individually but the second slideshow always overrides the first.

Comment: I think this is a new question now as I've answered your original question (and then some!) ;-)  Ask a new question and include your current code, and what is being emitted, and what's happening. (and add a comment here with a link to it, otherwise I'll miss it).

Comment: Yes, thanks for taking the time and pointing me towards wp_localize_script

Comment: @Markol - my pleasure, thanks for the accept.  With re to multiple instances of the slider not playing nice with each other...  Ask a new question about this and you'll get answers about that from people who know more about JS, JQ and that slider than I do ;-)

Answer (score 0):

1) you need to use global

```
$myvar ='123';

add_action('blabla','your_func');
function your_func(){
global $myvar;
}
```

2) OR, use **do_action**:
- [can I pass arguments to my function through add_action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843356/can-i-pass-arguments-to-my-function-through-add-action)

Comment: You don't need to use a global variable for this. See Sepster's answer.