# How to pass argument in PHP (Wordpress, Genesis)

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create a custom Author page for each author on my multi-author site. (I am using the Genesis Framework for Wordpress.)

There are two tasks: 1. dynamically retrieve author info from database 2. display it using a hook. I have no problem with part 1, but trying to pass the info via a hook to get it to display where I want on the page has me stumped.

My approach is to create an author.php file. This is what I have so far:

```
<?php
// this is the function I want to use to output my stuff.
function include_author_info($author_info) {
    echo $author_info;
}

// now we want to add this action to the Genesis loop   
add_action( 'genesis_before_loop', 'include_author_info', 5, 1);

// now I populate the data I will feed to the function
// first: set curauth based on the current author 
$curauth = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', $author_name) : get_userdata(intval($author));   
// next: store the curauth name
$user_name = $curauth->display_name;
// additionally: store the user bio for the curauth
$user_bio = $curauth->user_description;
// concatenate the name and bio into one formatted string
$formatted_user_info = "<h2> " . $user_name . "</h2><br /><p>" . $user_bio . "</p>";
// for testing purposes, I output the concatenated and formatted name/bio
echo $formatted_user_info;

// finally, I execute the action
do_action('include_author_info', $formatted_user_info);

//* Run the Genesis loop
genesis();
```

I know that I'm retrieving the author name and author bio correctly and also formatting it for display correctly because the test line outputs exactly the info I want. (Site is visible here: http://difficultrun.nathanielgivens.com/author/nathaniel/)

However, the actual function (include_author_info) does absolutely nada. It seems like the easiest thing in the world, I just want to pass a string to that function and output it. It's a 1-line function. But it won't work. I can output a constant like "Hello, world!" or whatever exactly where I want it to go, but I can't pass the argument.

I've already asked for help on the Genesis forums (no luck) and done research. I found these two pages helpful, but they didn't solve my problem:
[can I pass arguments to my function through add_action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843356/can-i-pass-arguments-to-my-function-through-add-action)
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_action

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Are you calling the function with do_action and also trying to execute it with the genesis_before_loop hook? My guess is that it is executing via the hook and doesn't have any parameters passed to it.If you are going to execute your function via the hook, can you remove the parameter and retrieve the author info in your function body?

Comment: >>Are you calling the function with do_action and also trying to execute it with the genesis_before_loop hook?<<

What I'd researched indicated that if you want to pass parameters, you had to do an add_action first and a do_action second, where the parameters actually come from the do_action. So, that's what I'm attempting to do.

>>Can you remove the parameter and retrieve the author info in your function body?<<

That's where I started 3 weeks ago, but it never worked that way either. I don't know if the $curauth line doesn't work in the context of the function, or if it's a display issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my research, the simple answer is that you cannot pass a parameter to a custom function when you're adding that function via a hook. It's not possible.

However, you can declare the variable that you want to pass as a global variable, and then write your function to access that global variable. I tried that out, and it worked. Here is my complete code:

```
<?php

// now I populate the data I will feed to the function
// first: set curauth based on the current author 
$curauth = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', $author_name) : get_userdata(intval($author));   
// next: store the curauth name
$user_name = $curauth->display_name;
// additionally: store the user bio for the curauth
$user_bio = $curauth->user_description;
// create a global variable my function can access
global $formatted_user_info;
// concatenate the name and bio into one formatted string
$formatted_user_info = "<h2> " . $user_name . "</h2><br /><p>" . $user_bio . "</p>";
// for testing purposes, I output the concatenated and formatted name/bio
// echo $formatted_user_info;

// now we want to add this action to the Genesis loop   
add_action( 'genesis_before_loop', 'include_author_info');

// this is the function I want to use to output my stuff.
function include_author_info($author_info) {
    global $formatted_user_info;
    echo $formatted_user_info;
}

//* Run the Genesis loop
genesis();
```

The article I found that helped me get this working is here: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/pass-variable-to-function-in-add_action

Answer (score 0):

I still think the genesis_before_loop action is firing without your parameter. Try outputting some debug info there.

```
function include_author_info($author_info) {
    echo "In author info function - value of param [" . $author_info . "]";

}
```

And put a line right above do_action

```
echo "executing action";
// finally, I execute the action
do_action('include_author_info', $formatted_user_info);
```

Let me know the output.

Comment: This is the output that I get from the function: 

In author info function - value of param []

The text "executing action" also shows up along with the rest of the debug text.

I'm not sure how this helps, though. I don't know how else to pass a parameter to my function other than the do_action. 

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Does "In author info . . . " only display once or more than once? And where is "executing action" in relation to that?

Comment: "In author info..." displays a single time. It displays in the genesis_before_loop position. The "executing action" line displays at the very top of the page, before the opening html tag.

Comment: OK - if your action was working, it would display again. That means is executing automatically and at the wrong time for what you are doing. Why don't you try creating your own action instead of hooking into the Genesis one?

Comment: I don't know how to create my own action that will display at the appropriate place in the body. I guess I just thought that was the whole point of Genesis, that it let you easily hook into their framework, and I'm shocked that you can't do something as simple as pass a parameter while you're hooking into it. 

If I really can't figure this out, I'll probably just create individual files for each author and hardcode the damn information that way, but I just can't believe there isn't a simpler way to pass a parameter. :-(

Comment: If you wanted something easy that works, you could put all the functionality inside your function, put the function at the top of your page template and call the function wherever you need the display.

Comment: I figured out how to do it with a global variable: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/pass-variable-to-function-in-add_action

Comment: Actually, I started out putting all the functionality inside the function, but it didn't work for some reason. I think that there's something weird about $curauth that only lets it work in certain contexts. But, what you're describing was actually what I tried to accomplish first. (There's always the possibility that I just screwed it up, since I know more PHP now then when I started.)

In any case, thanks very much for helping me debug this. That was very kind of you.