# How can I pass a PHP variable to a JavaScript function in WordPress?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to pass an element ID value to `add_action()`, which on its turn sets up the JS for Slick Slider in the footer.

The result I get is:

```
$("#").slick({...
```

But what I want is:

```
$("#rtt_grid_carrousel_5bd9bbeabd625").slick({...
```

This is my code so far:

```
$uniqid = uniqid('rtt_grid_carrousel_');
js_rtt_grid_carrousel( $uniqid );


function js_rtt_grid_carrousel( $uniqid ) {
    add_action('wp_footer', function( $uniqid ) {
        ?>
            <script id="rtt_grid_carrousel" type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#<?php echo $uniqid ?>").slick({
                        dots: false,
                        arrows: false,
                        infinite: false,
                        slidesToShow: 1,
                        slidesToScroll: 1,
                        draggable: false,
                        vertical: false,
                        centerMode: false,
                        adaptiveHeight: true,
                        // fade: true,
                        // cssEase: "linear",
                    });


                });
            </script>
        <?php
    });
}
```

**--EDIT--**
Edit for along the road.
So, we've found out the php var does gets passed to

```
 js_rtt_grid_carrousel()
```

But not to

```
add_action('wp_footer', function(){...}); inside that function
```

Comment: Seems like this should work, but I'm not highly experienced with PHP. Maybe try outputting the variable to the page at several places and see if it's correct all the way through.

Comment: In this line  $("#<?php echo $uniqid ?>").slick({

Put  $("#".<?php echo $uniqid ?>."").slick({

Comment: you shouldn't mix PHP and JS - it's bad practice that leads to unexpected behaviour. Create a hidden input or a hidden DOM element with data- attributes

Comment: or better yet, there's no conditional statements I see, so why not if/else if $uniqid is valid - if it is, add a generic class that slick targets in a .js file

Comment: @wadleo not valid - closing PHP allows HTML - so OP code is fine

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs, I'm having trouble seeing the risk here, and adding an element (and then parsing it with jQuery) seems overly complicated in this case. Care to elaborate?

Comment: @isherwood the server doesn't parse client-side code. ^^ probably the reason nothing is returning, because it's not being parsed properly.

Comment: According to [this article](https://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/php-js/scalar.php), PHP does indeed parse "browser-side" code. How is this scenario different?

Comment: @isherwood It does - but not all the time, 100% of the time. It's one of those things - it usually is ok, but in some/a lot of cases - it doesn't. However, that aside maybe `$uniqid` is null to begin with - lemme ask OP

Comment: try var_dumping this: `$uniqid` - does it contain a value to begin with?

Comment: Try using a class and you won't need to echo something

Comment: The reason I want to use a (unique) id  is that I use slick slider multiple times per page. Some are rendered by the same function. Hence the unique id. If I target a general class all the sliders get the same settings.

Passing the element id is the first test. Later I want also to pass slider settings.

Comment: var_dump() works fine directly in the function. But is not passed in add_action('wp_footer', function( $thisDoesNotGetsPassed  ){});
Inside this function is is null.
So the goal first should be to pass it into add_action( function() ), right?

Comment: @wadleo you still need to output content by echoing the return value of a function ...

Comment: @Tim do you not do `add_action('wp_footer', functionName($uniqId));`?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs That throws me an error: "Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah! I found it! :) You guys gave me some stuff to think about. [And searching along I found this here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34168439/7295693)
.

```
$uniqid = uniqid('rtt_grid_carrousel_');
js_rtt_grid_carrousel( $uniqid );


function js_rtt_grid_carrousel( $uniqid ) {
    add_action('wp_footer', function() use ( $uniqid ) {
        ?>
            <script id="rtt_grid_carrousel" type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#<?php echo $uniqid ?>").slick({
                        dots: false,
                        arrows: false,
                        infinite: false,
                        slidesToShow: 1,
                        slidesToScroll: 1,
                        draggable: false,
                        vertical: false,
                        centerMode: false,
                        adaptiveHeight: true,
                        // fade: true,
                        // cssEase: "linear",
                    });


                });
            </script>
        <?php
    });
}
```

Focus on the "use" in:

```
add_action('wp_footer', function() use ( $uniqid ) {...});
```

I'll have to look more into "use" to see what this is, but it works! :) Thanks all!

Comment: Later I can replace $uniqid with $args to pass more settings in an array().