# How to pass php variable to wordpress AJAX handler

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

Struggling to pass through some php variables into my ajax handler function in functions.php

Example provided below doesn't work, probably has something to do with the hooks but I can't find any info on how to do this:

```
/*Unsubscribe*/
$test_variable = "derp";

function user_unsubscribe($test_variable){
  echo json_encode($test_variable);
  wp_die();
};

add_action('wp_ajax_user_unsubscribe', 'user_unsubscribe');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_user_unsubscribe', 'user_unsubscribe');
```

Comment: Try: add_action('wp_ajax_user_unsubscribe', 'user_unsubscribe', 10, 1); and add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_user_unsubscribe', 'user_unsubscribe', 10, 1);

Comment: Those are set by default, tried it anyway, no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it with this solution: [can I pass arguments to my function through add_action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843356/can-i-pass-arguments-to-my-function-through-add-action)

Working code solution is:

```
/*Unsubscribe*/
$test_variable = "derp";

function user_unsubscribe($test_variable){
  echo json_encode($test_variable);
  wp_die();
};

add_action('wp_ajax_user_unsubscribe', function() use ($test_variable){
  user_unsubscribe($test_variable);
});

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_user_unsubscribe', function() use ($test_variable){
  user_unsubscribe($test_variable);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass that PHP variable in ajax data. Please check below files in which I had send the "test_variable" Value to Ajax Function from jQuery.

Jquery File Code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    
    $('#btn').on('click',function(){
      $.ajax({ 
           data: {action: 'get_listing_names','test': global.test_variable},
           type: 'post',
           url: global.ajax,
           success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
          }
      });
    });
});
```

Functions.php file Code.

```
<?php
/**
 * Enqueue scripts and styles.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
function ja_global_enqueues() {

    wp_enqueue_script(
        'global',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/global.js',
        array( 'jquery' ),
        '1.0.0',
        true
    );
    wp_localize_script(
        'global',
        'global',
        array(
            'ajax' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
            'test_variable' => 'Test Value',
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ja_global_enqueues' );


add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_listing_names', 'ajax_listings');
add_action('wp_ajax_get_listing_names', 'ajax_listings');


function ajax_listings() {

    $test_variable = $_POST['test_variable'];


    wp_send_json_success( $test_variable );        

}
```

Comment: That's fine for information you can share publicly but I have to keep the data I'm passing through private.

Answer (score 0):

The prefered way to pass variables to ajax is to add them to the request and read them from `$_GET` or `$_POST` [official documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

If you need other variables you'll either have to use [globals](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) or call a extra function.

favorite

Struggling to pass through some php variables into my ajax handler function in functions.php

Example provided below doesn't work, probably has something to do with the hooks but I can't find any info on how to do this:

```
function user_unsubscribe(){
  $test_variable = get_test_variable();

  echo json_encode($test_variable);
  wp_die();
};

add_action('wp_ajax_user_unsubscribe', 'user_unsubscribe');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_user_unsubscribe', 'user_unsubscribe');

function get_test_variable() {
    // here get/fetch your variable;

    /*Unsubscribe*/
    $test_variable = "derp";

    return $test_variable;
}
```