# Wordpress - How to pass argument to add_action while the method is inside a class?

Tags: php, wordpress, class, parameters, arguments

in my `functions.php` I have

```
require 'autoloader.php';
add_action('init', 'MyClass::make');
```

and in my `MyClass` class I have

```
class MyClass {
    public static function make($type) {
        var_dump($type);die;
    }
}
```

but the output of `var_dump` is `string(0) ""`. What I want is to pass the argument to this class as `$type`. What I tried was to pass it through `do_action` however I think it is not best practice.

How can I pass argument to a method which is inside a class for `add_action`?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wordpress Documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/#usage):
add_action can have up to 4 arguments, where fourth is count of arguments passable to function.

```
add_action( 'init', 'MyClass::make', 10 /*Action priority, default is 10*/, 1  );
```

Then you can pass anything as one argument fo function:

```
do_action( 'init', "Here I am!" );
```

Comment: Also this question is a duplicate of "[can I pass arguments to my function through add_action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843356/can-i-pass-arguments-to-my-function-through-add-action)".

Comment: As I said I had used that `do_action` you mentioned! The problem is that when I do that, for `do_action('add_meta_boxes', 'my-post-type')`, it returns `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function add_meta_box()`. I think because there are two `do_action`s, one from wordpress one from my custom code, or maybe it is executed sooner than that one and returns this error!

Comment: According to your comment, the error you're getting is because the function `add_meta_boxes` is not included when it's being called. Also in PHP is not possible to have two functions of same name. I would recommend you to try print some stack traces and check where this error comes from.