# WordPress - Cannot create taxonomy inside conditional statement

Tags: php, wordpress

My goal is to inside a plugin pull all the posts/pages/custom post types in the project and create a custom taxonomy if it does not exist. Whenever the plugin goes inside of the if statement the php stops running on the page. As you can see in the foreach statement, I echo the post type name and the taxonomy associated with it.

I just want to create a custom taxonomy on a publicly available post type if the taxonomy does not exist.

I am able to run the taxonomy code that is inside the if statement inside the functions.php file so long as I replace the variables with the proper post types.

I also tried to instead of using add_action( 'init', 'custom_taxo_cpt_taxonomy', 1 ); just call the function directly via custom_taxo_cpt_taxonomy() on the same line as add_action( 'init', 'custom_taxo_cpt_taxonomy', 1 );

The echos/var_dumps are able to give me the post types and taxonomies associated without issue on the page so I know that is being pulled fine on the page.

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'public'   => true,
);

$output = 'names';
$operator = 'and';

$post_types = get_post_types( $args, $output, $operator ); 

foreach ( $post_types  as $post_type ) {
    $cpt_taxo_ar = get_object_taxonomies($post_type);
    $cpt_taxo_ar = array_shift($cpt_taxo_ar);
    echo '<p>' . $post_type . ' category: ' . $cpt_taxo_ar . '</p>';
    if($cpt_taxo_ar != $post_type . '_custom_taxo'){
        echo $post_type . '_custom_taxo';

        // Register CustomTaxo Tags Taxonomy
        function custom_taxo_cpt_taxonomy() {

            $labels = array(
                'name'                       => _x( 'CustomTaxo Tags', 'CustomTaxo Tags', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
                'singular_name'              => _x( 'CustomTaxo Tag', 'CustomTaxo Tag', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
                'menu_name'                  => __( 'CustomTaxo Tags', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
                'all_items'                  => __( 'All Tags', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
                'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent Tag', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
                'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent Tag:', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
                'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Tag Name', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
                'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Tag', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
                'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Tag', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
                'update_item'                => __( 'Update Tag', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
                'view_item'                  => __( 'View Tag', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
                'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate items with commas', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
                'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove tags', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
                'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
                'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular tags', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
                'search_items'               => __( 'Search tags', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
                'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
                'no_terms'                   => __( 'No items', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
                'items_list'                 => __( 'Tags list', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
                'items_list_navigation'      => __( 'Tags list navigation', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
            );

            $args = array(
                'labels'                     => $labels,
                'hierarchical'               => false,
                'public'                     => true,
                'show_ui'                    => true,
                'show_admin_column'          => true,
            );

            register_taxonomy( $post_type . '_custom_taxo', 'page', $args );

        } // end taxo function
            add_action( 'init', 'custom_taxo_cpt_taxonomy', 1 );
    } //end for loop
}
?>
```

Comment: Remove latest `,` on your arrays. All example I have found use `0` as priority for [`add_action`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/). Maybe try this : `add_action( 'init', 'custom_taxo_cpt_taxonomy', 0 );`. Maybe these can help you [create-custom-taxonomies-wordpress](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/create-custom-taxonomies-wordpress/) and here [wordpress-custom-post-type-cpt-and-taxonomy-hello-world-tutorial-tips-and-tricks](https://crunchify.com/how-to-create-wordpress-custom-post-type-cpt-and-taxonomy-hello-world-tutorial-tips-and-tricks/)

Comment: Good catch on the arrays, I removed the latest ','. I also set the priority to be '0' for the add_action. When I comment out the add_action() and just leave the custom_taxo_cpt_taxonomy() function the page still gets cut short. I think something inside of the function is causing the fail but I cannot find what.

Comment: Have you enable error display in PHP ? `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: AHA! I get this error: "Cannot redeclare custom_taxo_cpt_taxonomy()". That explains why it was failing, now the question is, how can I programmatically change the name of the function so that in each foreach loop it has a different name?

Comment: Maybe try with anonymous function : `$custom_taxo_cpt_taxonomy = function () { }` and `add_action( 'init', $custom_taxo_cpt_taxonomy, 1 );` according to the documentation `add_action( string $tag, callable $function_to_add, int $priority = 10, int $accepted_args = 1 )`

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation:

```php
add_action( string $tag, callable $function_to_add, int $priority = 10, int $accepted_args = 1 )`
```

To resolve the issue : `"Cannot redeclare custom_taxo_cpt_taxonomy()"`

`custom_taxo_cpt_taxonomy` must be `callable` so in a loop to avoid name declaration issue, anonymous function can be used like this:

```php
$custom_taxo_cpt_taxonomy = function() { ... }
```

Finally anonymous doesn't work because WordPress use `call_user_func_array` in [class-wp-hook](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php) at `apply_filters` and not something like `$myCallback();`

**EDIT: Function not anonymous outside the loop**

```php
<?php
function custom_taxo_cpt_taxonomy($params) {
  register_taxonomy( $params['post_type'] . '_custom_taxo', 'page', $params['args'] );
} // end taxo function


foreach ( $post_types  as $post_type ) {
  $cpt_taxo_ar = get_object_taxonomies($post_type);
  $cpt_taxo_ar = array_shift($cpt_taxo_ar);
  echo '<p>' . $post_type . ' category: ' . $cpt_taxo_ar . '</p>';

  if($cpt_taxo_ar != $post_type . '_custom_taxo'){
    echo $post_type . '_custom_taxo';

    // Register CustomTaxo Tags Taxonomy
    // function custom_taxo_cpt_taxonomy() { <= issue here
    // $custom_taxo_cpt_taxonomy = function() { <= other issue
    $labels = array(
      'name'                       => _x( 'CustomTaxo Tags', 'CustomTaxo Tags', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
      'singular_name'              => _x( 'CustomTaxo Tag', 'CustomTaxo Tag', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
      'menu_name'                  => __( 'CustomTaxo Tags', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
      'all_items'                  => __( 'All Tags', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
      'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent Tag', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
      'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent Tag:', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
      'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Tag Name', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
      'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Tag', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
      'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Tag', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
      'update_item'                => __( 'Update Tag', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
      'view_item'                  => __( 'View Tag', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
      'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate items with commas', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
      'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove tags', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
      'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
      'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular tags', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
      'search_items'               => __( 'Search tags', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
      'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
      'no_terms'                   => __( 'No items', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
      'items_list'                 => __( 'Tags list', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
      'items_list_navigation'      => __( 'Tags list navigation', 'custom_taxo_domain' )
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels,
        'hierarchical'               => false,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true
    );

    $params = array(
      'post_type' => $post_type,
      'args' => $args
    );

    // Pass callable not anonymous function
    add_action( 'init', array('custom_taxo_cpt_taxonomy', $params), 1);
  } //end for loop
}
?>
```

**EDIT : IMPORTANT**

So the code bellow **doesn't work**: `syntax error, unexpected 'add_action' (T_STRING).`

```php
<?php
$args = array(
  'public' => true
);

$output = 'names';
$operator = 'and';

$post_types = get_post_types( $args, $output, $operator ); 

foreach ( $post_types  as $post_type ) {
    $cpt_taxo_ar = get_object_taxonomies($post_type);
    $cpt_taxo_ar = array_shift($cpt_taxo_ar);
    echo '<p>' . $post_type . ' category: ' . $cpt_taxo_ar . '</p>';
    if($cpt_taxo_ar != $post_type . '_custom_taxo'){
        echo $post_type . '_custom_taxo';

        // Register CustomTaxo Tags Taxonomy
        // function custom_taxo_cpt_taxonomy() { <= issue here
        // Create anonymous function
        $custom_taxo_cpt_taxonomy = function() {

            $labels = array(
                'name'                       => _x( 'CustomTaxo Tags', 'CustomTaxo Tags', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
                'singular_name'              => _x( 'CustomTaxo Tag', 'CustomTaxo Tag', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
                'menu_name'                  => __( 'CustomTaxo Tags', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
                'all_items'                  => __( 'All Tags', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
                'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent Tag', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
                'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent Tag:', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
                'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Tag Name', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
                'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Tag', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
                'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Tag', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
                'update_item'                => __( 'Update Tag', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
                'view_item'                  => __( 'View Tag', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
                'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate items with commas', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
                'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove tags', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
                'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
                'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular tags', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
                'search_items'               => __( 'Search tags', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
                'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
                'no_terms'                   => __( 'No items', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
                'items_list'                 => __( 'Tags list', 'custom_taxo_domain' ),
                'items_list_navigation'      => __( 'Tags list navigation', 'custom_taxo_domain' )
            );

            $args = array(
                'labels'                     => $labels,
                'hierarchical'               => false,
                'public'                     => true,
                'show_ui'                    => true,
                'show_admin_column'          => true
            );

            register_taxonomy( $post_type . '_custom_taxo', 'page', $args );

        } // end taxo function

        // Pass callable anonymous function
        add_action( 'init', $custom_taxo_cpt_taxonomy, 1 );
    } //end for loop
}
?>
```

`,` in the end of arrays creates an extra empty field.

Comment: Although the anonymous function makes sense, I get a syntax error after changing it to an anonymous function on the add_action: syntax error, unexpected 'add_action' (T_STRING).

Comment: I don't see why it not works: [PHP callable](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/language.types.callable.php) _Apart from common user-defined function, anonymous functions can also be passed to a callback parameter._ I think you have to create the function (not anonymous) outside the loop with some parameters and call it in add_action something like this `add_action('init', array('custom_taxo_cpt_taxonomy', $params), 1);` ad_action should work like [function.call-user-func](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.call-user-func.php)

Comment: You can optimize what you want dynamic or not with parameters in/and the function

Comment: Got it. I moved the taxonomy function outside of the for loop and changed it to be a regular function instead of anonymous. I dont get the 500 error anymore but it still doesnt seem to run the function. This is the function declaration: function customtaxo_taxo_create($post_type) {...}

this is the add_action: 
add_action('init', array('customtaxo_taxo_create', $post_type), 1);

Do I understand that right?

Comment: Yes it is ! Maybe try to use an array as parameter `add_action('init', array('customtaxo_taxo_create', array($post_type)), 1);` as [function.call-user-func-array](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.call-user-func-array.php) . we are close to the goal. I found this post with many solutions : [can-i-pass-arguments-to-my-function-through-add-action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843356/can-i-pass-arguments-to-my-function-through-add-action)

Comment: Sorry, this is over my head by this point and I thank you for your patience. So far ive tried these two add_action calls:

add_action( 'init', array('custom_taxo_cpt_taxonomy', $params), 1);

add_action('init', array('custom_taxo_cpt_taxonomy', array($post_type)), 1);

Comment: Another syntax with close: `add_action('init', function() use ($post_type) { // your function content here } );` founded on the post.

Comment: yes I tried that one as well after I put all the taxonomy labels and args inside of it. Would converting the taxonomy function into a class make any difference?

Comment: Maybe with class and storing post_type value using object properties is a better solution. I prefer using objects personally.

Comment: I have forgot this, you can find a complete source of a little widget I made : [xtrmtotopwidget](https://github.com/shim-sao/wordpress-widget-to-top/blob/master/wp_xtrmtotop/admin/xtrmtotopwidget.php). I use object and I use `$this->options` _as parameters_ with that call `add_action('wp_footer', array($this, 'setScriptHeader'), 10, 1);`

Comment: I tried doing it in a class but had no luck either. I dont have any errors thrown or warning. Not sure how else to get this accomplished as I dont have anyone with more PHP experience than I do to help me.