# How to persist file upload form data between submission events

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I'm trying to retain uploaded file info while changing other form toggles/parameters and avoid having to re-upload the file each time. Is it possible to persist the file upload data?

**HTML for form**

```
<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="fileUpload" id="fileUpload">
<input type="submit" value="Upload This" name="upload">
<input type="submit" value="Preview" name="preview">
<div class="col text-center justify-content-center">
<div class="bmd-form-group">
<label class="bmd-label-static" for="txtcolor">Choose the Text Color</label>
<input type="color" id="txtcolor" name="txtcolor" value="#000000">
<label for="body">Body</label>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col text-center justify-content-center">
<div class="form-check">
<label class="form-check-label">
<input id="iversion" class="form-check-input" name="invertBox" type="checkbox" value="">Invert
<span class="form-check-sign">
<span class="check"></span>
</span>
</label>
</div>
</div>
<?php
if($previewOk){
    echo "<img class='w-100 h-100' src='data:image/jpeg;base64, $imgData'  />"; ?>
<?php } ?>
<a href="<?php $add_to_cart = do_shortcode('[add_to_cart_url id="'.$post->ID.'"]'); echo $add_to_cart;?>"class="more">Buy now</a>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
$previewOk=0;

if($_FILES["fileUpload"]["tmp_name"]){
    $myfile=$_FILES["fileUpload"]["tmp_name"];
}


if(!empty($_POST) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $file_url = move_file_test(); //moves file to directory
    $theid = create_download(); //creates a file link
    create_download_version($theid, $file_url); //more file stuff

}

if(isset($_POST['txtcolor'])){
    $color = $_POST['txtcolor'];
    $myfile = change_color($myfile); //some function that alters the $myfile and regenenerates
}

if(isset($_POST["preview"])) {
    $imgData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($myfile));
    previewOk = 1;
}
```

I'd like `$myfile` to stick around after the form is submitted and only update when uploading a different file. The intention is to access `$myfile` again in some other form based action - for example: changing the background color of an uploaded image file and previewing it without having to launch a file browser and start over each iteration.

**UPDATE**

Added some additional context to further illustrate. `$myfile` persistence would be nice for previewing the file (let's say it is an image file) and also for performing form specified transforms (such as applying updates from the color picker form input)

Integration with woocommerce (in case the image is for purchase) is causing some headaches due to my limited experience with wordpress hooks and actions. I would like to set and then pass some parameters from the form during the `add_to_cart` shortcode which will have a hook into the `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta` method, but the form submission and the shortcode do not share any namespace, and the form resubmission wipes the variables I'd want to pass to the hook (once I figure out *[closures](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34168439)*?)

I have not tried Ajax, but I have a feeling it is probably the best solution.

**UPDATED SOLUTION**

I was able to get it working after applying some small changes to the solution provided. I marked where I made edits in the code with `// *** EDITED HERE ***`.

**JS**

```
<script>
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) { 

    // Prevent form submission
    $('#form-id').on( "submit", function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    // Handle file selection and upload
    $('#fileUpload').on("change", function() {

        var files = this.files;

        if (!files.length) return;

        var file = files[0];

        var data = new FormData(); 
        data.append( 'action', 'upload' );
        data.append( 'nonce', window.wp_data.nonce );
        data.append( 'file', file );

        $.ajax({
            url: window.wp_data.ajax_url,
            type: 'POST', 
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json', 
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function( respond, status, jqXHR ){

                if( typeof respond.error === 'undefined' ){                    
                    $('#preview').html(respond.data.preview); 
                    $('#add_to_cart').html(respond.data.add_to_cart); 
                } 

            },
            error: function( jqXHR, status, errorThrown ){
                console.log( 'AJAX requert error: ', status, jqXHR );
            }
        })
    });
    // Processing other fields on Submit button click. This is a case if you have to process many fields.
    $('#submit').on( "click", function( event ) {
        var data = { 
            action: 'process',
            nonce: window.wp_data.nonce        
    };


        $.each(
            // *** EDITED HERE ***
            // changed $('#form_id').serializeArray() to $( ":input" ).serializeArray() 
            // $('#form_id').serializeArray() returned an empty array 
            $( ":input" ).serializeArray(), 
            function (i, field) {
                if (data[field.name]) {
                    if (!data[field.name].push) {
                        data[field.name] = [data[field.name]];
                    }
                    data[field.name].push(field.value || '');
                } else {
                    data[field.name] = field.value || '';
                }
            }
        );
        $.post( 
            window.wp_data.ajax_url,
            data,
            function( respond ) {
                $('#preview').html(respond.data.preview); 
                $('#add_to_cart').html(respond.data.add_to_cart); 
            }, 
            "json"
        )
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
// Handle upload request
add_action( 'wp_ajax_upload', function () {
    check_ajax_referer( 'my-nonce', 'nonce' ); // Check security

    $data = [];
    //**** EDITED HERE *****
    // Needed to change $_FILES['fileUpload'] to $_FILES['file'] to match the ajax 
    if ( isset( $_FILES['file'] ) and !$_FILES['file']['error'] ) {
        $file_url = save_file_to_directory();

        $_SESSION['file_url'] = $file_url; // Save file_url to session for future use

        $data['preview'] = generate_preview( $file_url );
        $data['add_to_cart'] = generate_add_to_cart();

        wp_send_json_success( $data );
    }
    else {
        wp_send_json_error();
    }
    wp_die();
} );

// Handle fields request. I separate it for better understanding. You may merge this logic with wp_ajax_upload. 
add_action( 'wp_ajax_process', function () {
    check_ajax_referer( 'my-nonce', 'nonce' ); // Check security

    $file_url = $_SESSION['file_url']; // Remember $file_url from session

    $data = [];
    // ***** EDITED HERE ********
    // Not sure if $_REQUEST will also work since I did not check after the other edits  
    // I assume it will since $_POST is a specific $_REQUEST. $_POST works. 
    if ( isset( $_POST['txtcolor'] ) ) { // changed $_REQUEST['txtcolor'] to $_POST['txtcolor']
        $data['preview'] = apply_txtcolor( $file_url );
        $data['add_to_cart'] = generate_add_to_cart();
    }
    if ( isset( $_POST['invertBox'] ) ) { // changed $_REQUEST['invertBox'] to $_POST['invertBox']
        $data['preview'] = apply_invertBox( $file_url );
        $data['add_to_cart'] = generate_add_to_cart();
    }

    wp_send_json_success( $data );
    wp_die();
} );
```

Comment: The temp file gets deleted by PHP, once the script instance that received the upload request ends. You need to move the file to a different location, if you still want to have access to it afterwards. (Keep in mind that cleaning up left-over files would be your responsibility as well then.)

Comment: I think you would have to think about asynchronous solutions

Comment: Would be nice to see example of other form parameters as you have only file and submit in your form. Have you considered sending form via ajax to be able to choose whether to send the file along with other fields or not?

Comment: @EugeneIonichev I've updated my question to add more context. Hopefully it has not expanded beyond the limits of the initial question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use ajax to have a choice whether to send the file along with other fields or not. Session could be used to keep a file_url between requests.

I give you an algorithm below how everything can be organized.

**HTML**

```
<form id="form-id" method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="fileUpload" id="fileUpload">
    <div class="col text-center justify-content-center">
        <div class="bmd-form-group">
            <label class="bmd-label-static" for="txtcolor">Choose the Text Color</label>
            <input type="color" id="txtcolor" name="txtcolor" value="#000000">
            <label for="body">Body</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col text-center justify-content-center">
        <div class="form-check">
            <label class="form-check-label">
                <input id="iversion" class="form-check-input" name="invertBox" type="checkbox" value="">Invert <span class="form-check-sign">
<span class="check"></span> </span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    <div id="preview"></div>
    <div id="add_to_cart"></div>
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) { 

    // Prevent form submission
    $('#form-id').on( "submit", function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    // Handle file selection and upload
    $('#fileUpload').on("change", function() {

        var files = this.files;
        if (!files.length) return;

        var file = files[0];

        var data = new FormData();
        data.append( 'action', 'upload' );
        data.append( 'nonce', window.wp_data.nonce );
        data.append( 'file', file );
        $.ajax({
            url: window.wp_data.ajax_url,
            type: 'POST', 
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function( respond, status, jqXHR ){
                if( typeof respond.error === 'undefined' ){
                    $('#preview').html( respond.data.preview );
                    $('#add_to_cart').html( respond.data.add_to_cart );
                }
            },
            error: function( jqXHR, status, errorThrown ){
                console.log( 'AJAX requert error: ', status, jqXHR );
            }
        })
    });

    // Processing other fields on Submit button click. This is a case if you have to process many fields.
    $('#submit').on( "click", function( event ) {
        var data = { 
            action: 'process',
            nonce: window.wp_data.nonce
        };
        $.each(
            $('#form_id').serializeArray(), 
            function (i, field) { 
                if (data[field.name]) {
                    if (!data[field.name].push) {
                        data[field.name] = [data[field.name]];
                    }
                    data[field.name].push(field.value || '');
                } else {
                    data[field.name] = field.value || '';
                }
            }
        );
        $.post( 
            window.wp_data.ajax_url,
            data,
            function( respond ) {
                $('#preview').html( respond.data.preview );
                $('#add_to_cart').html( respond.data.add_to_cart );
            }, 
            "json"
        )
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
// This is an idea how to store uploaded file_url: use session vars
add_action( 'init', function () {
    if( !session_id() ) {
        session_start();
    }
}, 1);

// A trick to use nice wordpress ajax hooks at frontend
add_action( 'wp_head', function () {
    $variables = array (
        'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'), // Pass ajax_url to frontend
        'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('my-nonce') // Security
    );
    echo(
        '<script type="text/javascript">window.wp_data = ' .
        json_encode($variables) .
        ';</script>'
    );
} );

// Handle upload request
add_action( 'wp_ajax_upload', function () {
    check_ajax_referer( 'my-nonce', 'nonce' ); // Check security

    $data = [];
    if ( isset( $_FILES['fileUpload'] ) and !$_FILES['fileUpload']['error'] ) {
        $file_url = save_file_to_directory();
        #_SESSION['file_url'] = $file_url; // Save file_url to session for future use

        $data['preview'] = generate_preview( $file_url );
        $data['add_to_cart'] = generate_add_to_cart();

        wp_send_json_success( $data );
    }
    else {
        wp_send_json_error();
    }
    wp_die();
} );

// Handle fields request. I separate it for better understanding. You may merge this logic with wp_ajax_upload. 
add_action( 'wp_ajax_process', function () {
    check_ajax_referer( 'my-nonce', 'nonce' ); // Check security

    $file_url = #_SESSION['file_url']; // Remember $file_url from session

    $data = [];
    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['txtcolor'] ) ) {
        $data['preview'] = apply_txtcolor( $file_url );
        $data['add_to_cart'] = generate_add_to_cart();
    }
    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['invertBox'] ) ) {
        $data['preview'] = apply_invertBox( $file_url );
        $data['add_to_cart'] = generate_add_to_cart();
    }

    wp_send_json_success( $data );
    wp_die();
} );
```

Some moments could be made better or different way depending on the situation. This is just the idea of the algorithm.
Remember to delete image file in the right moment in case you don't need it anymore.

Comment: Thank you, Eugene. You've given me some excellent advice and steered me in the right direction.

Comment: Unfortunately as I implement this design, I am getting 400 errors maybe due to mismatch between accepted content types between client and server. Request  accepts `application/json, text/javascript` and Response accepts `text/html; charset=UTF-8`. I have tried passing JSON.stringify(data) in various places. It may be the output I am returning from the processing methods - such as `generate_preview`, `apply_invertBox` etc. As this output defines the html content of the form elements ex: `$('#preview').html( respond.data.preview )` I am returning a string of html? I'll post my solution

Comment: If you make the request as anonymous, try adding wp_ajax_nopriv_(action) hook also: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_nopriv_%28action%29

Comment: Thanks again, Eugene. I do so I will implement your suggestion. I am also going to take some time to break apart the code, read documentation and ensure I understand the ajax solution you have provided. I really appreciate how you took the time to break things out to make that easier